# How to convert exponential values to decimal values with vim

Tags: vim

I have a text file with two columns with numbers like this:

```
 0.00000000E+00   0.66244638E+00
 0.10000000E+01   0.66630906E+00
 0.20000000E+01   0.66920608E+00
 0.30000000E+01   0.67210299E+00
```

...

```
 0.59600000E+03   0.66341203E+02
 0.59700000E+03   0.66824037E+02
 0.59800000E+03   0.67403436E+02
 0.59900000E+03   0.67886269E+02
 0.60000000E+03   0.68369102E+02
```

How can I convert the values to decimal values with **vim** ?

Outcome:

```
 0.0   0.66244638
 1.0   0.66630906
```

...

```
 599.0   67.886269
 600.0   68.369102
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it, from Vim:

```
:%s/\v(\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+)/\=printf("%.1f\t%.8f", str2float(submatch(1)), str2float(submatch(2)))/
```

This needs a version of Vim compiled with `+float`.

The sane / smart / easy / fast way to do it, outside Vim:

```
awk '{ printf("%.1f\t%.8f\n", $1, $2) }' file.txt
```